# parse all value of a column

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a data table

and it contains some int type columns, some type double columns, some date  type columns

what i am trying to do is,

i want to do double.TryParse for double column, and if there is any value with it then it will store dbnull value in corresponding rows,

same thing i will do for date, int

since my data table could have 100000 records so i don't to run loop for each row

is it possible through linq or with any method

Thank You

Comment: @JensKloster , i can do it with loop, but with other methods, i want some concept

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is not good for batch operations. You should create a stored procedure in your DB and import it in your model (If you are using EF that is import function, if using LINQ to SQL then a simple drag and drop will do it).

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is no silver bullet for all problems where you need to loop over a (maybe very large) set of data. So if you want to go over each data set and change the values depending on some condition, a `foreach` loop is your friend.

LINQ is a query language to retrieve data and not some kind of super-fast way to alter large lists or other enumerable objects. It comes in handy if you want to get data from a given object applying some conditions or doing a `GroupBy` without ending up in a 20-lines unreadable mash of foreach-loops and if-statements.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if you'll do it in a loop or with linq, you'll still need to iterate over the entire data table ...

there's no silver bullet that will save you from doing the checks and inserts i'm afraid